# How can I advoice splitting integer?

Tags: java, regex, split, spaces

I'm trying to add spaces between numbers but as result some numbers get split and other sometimes lost.

Code:

```
String line = "321HELLO how do you do? $ah213 -20d1001x";
line = line.replaceAll("([^d]?)([\\d\\.]+)([^d]?)", "$1 $2 $3");
System.out.println(line);
```

result:

```
3 21 HELLO how do "you" do? $ah 213  - 2 0 d1 001 x
```

Rules:

No matter how big integer is dont split it in many parts.
$ + number ($123) or $ +letter + number ($abc123) dont add space before & after number.
Letter + number = separate it.

Wanted result:

```
321 HELLO how do "you" do? $ah213 -20 d 1001 x
```

Comment: Why isn't there a space here `$ah213` and how is this piece of code formed `d 1001 x` ? I mean I would expect it to be `d 1 001 x` ?

Comment: @HamZa, your logical interpretation is right since I didnt give enought informations. Added more informations, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One small mistake in your regex: `[^d]` should be `[^\\d]`, otherwise you're checking for the character `d` rather than the character class `\d`.

But it still inserts too many spaces, I don't really see a way to avoid that with your current regex.

**Something that works:**

```
String line = "321HELLO how do you do? $ah213 -20d1001x";
line = line.replaceAll("(?<=[-\\d.])(?=[^\\s-\\d.])|(?<!\\$[a-z]{0,1000})(?<=[^\\s-\\d.])(?=[-\\d.])", " ");
System.out.println(line);
```

prints:

```
321 HELLO how do you do? $ah213 -20 d 1001 x
```

**Explanation:**

`[-\\d.]` is what I presume you classify as "part of a number" (although a `.` alone will get treated as a number, which may not be desired) (you don't need to escape `.` inside `[]`).
`(?<=...)` is positive look-behind, meaning the previous characters match the pattern.
`(?=...)` is positive look-ahead, meaning the next characters match the pattern.
`(?<!...)` is negative look-behind, meaning the previous characters don't match the pattern.

So basically whenever you get to a place that is a switching point between number and not number, insert a space (if one doesn't already exist). And the negative look-behind prevents a space from being inserted whenever there is a `$` followed by 0-1000 (can't use `*` in look-behind) letters (will prevent spaces with `$123` and `$ah123`).

[Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**Additional note:**

Turns out you don't really need the `?<=` at all, this can be matched regularly.

```
replaceAll("([-\\d.])(?=[^\\s-\\d.])|(?<!\\$[a-z]{0,1000})([^\\s-\\d.])(?=[-\\d.])", "$1$2 ")
```

Comment: just now added explanation why it should not separate `$ah213`.

Comment: @user1768615 For the second regex? No. The only groups / things in brackets are `([-\\d.])` and `([^\\s-\\d.])` (look-around isn't a capturing group). Note that only one of them will be populated because of the `|`, but if a group isn't populated, it will just be blank, so adding both is fine. Look-ahead's are not included in the part of the string that the regex matches (it's checked, but not included), so they don't need to / can't be replaced.